# Проверка целой строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```js
var re = /((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)/;
var str4 = "1300.6.7.8";
console.log(re.test(str4));
```

почему тест выдаёт тру, объясните пожалуйста.
цель - проверяю IP v.4 address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить `^` (*начало строки*) в начало и `$` (*конец строки*) в конец шаблона для проверки на начало и конец строки. Без  `^` и `$` находится подстрока.

```js
var re = /((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)/;
var str4 = "1300.6.7.8";
console.log(str4.match(re));

var re2 = /^(((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d))$/;
console.log(str4.match(re2));
console.log(re2.test(str4));
```

Comment: @vp_arth, `[01]?\d?\d` - первый 0 намеренно разрешён. С другой стороны, `0000.6.7.8` уже не ожидается - да, странновато :)

Comment: В принципе, ничего плохого, думаю в 00.00.00.00 нет) Ну да ладно)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, в чём смысл изменения ответа?

Comment: @Qwertiy Во-первых, почему-то мне показалось, что это мой ответ :) Извините. Во-вторых, захотелось конкретно указать, что куда надо добавить, чтобы у будущих посетителей не возникало вопросов, как такие проблемы решаются.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, в общем случае, если просто добавить в начало и конец, то может получиться неверно. Пример: `abc|xyz`.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше обойтись без регулярных выражений:

```js
function isIPv4(ip) {
  let parts = ip.split('.');
  if (parts.length !== 4) return false;
  return parts.map(p => +p)
       .every(p => p >= 0 && p < 256);    
}

[
  '127.0.0.1',
  '1.2a.3.4',
  '256.0.0.0'
].forEach(ip => console.log(ip, isIPv4(ip)));
```