# PHP Regexp точное совпадение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, есть поиск по ключу -  `preg_grep("/(page|sort)/", array_keys($query))`

Как исправить регулярное выражение, чтобы оно не возвращало true если ключ массива равен к примеру "pageee" или "aaasort"? То есть точное совпадение, или "page", или "sort".

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php - Проверяет, присутствует ли в массиве указанный ключ или индекс

Comment: `/^(page|sort)$/`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в регулярном выражении избавиться от совпадения в альтернативном выборе неявных строк?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765882/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%8f%d0%b2)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [RegExp метод test, почему true](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743426/regexp-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-test-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$q = [
    'page'   =>'01',
    'sort'   =>'02',
    'pageee' =>'11',
    'aaasort'=>'12'
];

$ret = preg_grep("/^(page|sort)$/", array_keys($q));

print_r($ret); // Array ( [0] => page [1] => sort )
```